# Applying Patch 1093 in Solr 4.7.2

Tags: solr, ant, patch

I am trying to implement Multiple Queries Single Request feature in solr and found this path SOLR-1093. I have two options to add this feature. First is to build the code, get a war file and deployed it in tomcat and use it Or to apply the patch to solr trunk.

First option didn't work, am getting the following error:

**common.compile-core:
    [javac] Compiling 133 source files to \lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\build\test-framework\classes\java
    [javac] error: error reading \lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\test-framework\lib\ant-1.8.2.jar; error in opening zip file
    [javac] 1 error**

**BUILD FAILED
\lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\solr\build.xml:343: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\module-build.xml:97: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\common-build.xml:489: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\common-build.xml:1621: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.**

Second Option: i don't know how to apply patch. I have seen many pages, where it is asked to refer this wiki page (https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Working_With_Patches). 
But that didn't help. There it is given as solr trunk. am not sure, from where to download that and how to apply this patch?

Can anyone please help in providing solution to either of the options would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody can help on this? or please provide your suggestions in applying a patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build the code successfully.

common.compile-core: [javac] Compiling 133 source files to \lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\build\test-framework\classes\java [javac] error: error reading \lucene-solr-multi-request-handler\lucene\test-framework\lib\ant-1.8.2.jar; error in opening zip file [javac] 1 error

This error was due to the ant-1.8.2.jar file. It was corrupted. Downloaded new jar and replaced it. That worked.

This patch is also working fine with 4.3 version. Now am trying to implement in 4.7 version.